# Dynamic UIWebView height and UITableViewCell resizing

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, resizable

First of all, I have tried many questions and answer from SO and google, none of the answers or tricks still solve my problem. And I am still having a problem at tableview resizing. So, I want everyone to know that I do post that question after giving much time at solving this case. So, any help is welcome, especially at Swift and Storyboard.

Here is my design

[image]

As you can see,my `tableview cell` is dynamic data which is from a server. So,I did reusable table view cell.But another problem is I got the view inside `UITableViewCell` and worst,inside `UIView`,its `UIWebView`.

And I still can't resize it because the `UIView` is the parent of `UIWebView`. My `UIWebView` height will be dynamic base on data I got from the server which is just an HTML string. When it finish loaded. I need to resize `UIView` to appear `UIButton` as soon as `UIView` resize I also need to set `UITableViewCell` height.

Any help? If I make it out, that answer will be helpful for everyone else who is seeking answer for such problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing that you can try:

- First set the constraints on UIView to the edges of contentView(of UITableViewCell), and also the constraints for the inside elements (with respect to the UIView).
- Second, base on the data that you receive from the web service, use the method tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: (in UITableViewDelegate), to return the size that you want.

Comment: That can only resize the UITableViewCell base on UIView.Not the UIWebView.;(

Comment: No, on the contrary ,that will set the UIView, based on the UITableViewCell, and UIWebView based on the UIView . Give me a few minutes , I will make a small example .

Comment: I tried your example.But,i don't want to enable UIWebView Scroll feature.Mean i will disable user-interaction on UIWebView.And I will not load website by using url inside uiwebview.I will just load html tag instead which are come from the server on each uitableviewcell.So,i need to load full height of html page inside webview.

Comment: It's the same, the only thing that you need to do, it's on the StoryBoard disable ScrollView and establish a way to get the Height of the HTML that you're going to load (that depends of your need).

Or you can use an UIScrollView, and create the UIWebView Dynamically and get the webView.scrollView.contentSize (and update the constraints dynamically). The difference with the first, it's that I first load the page and then set the Height.